# How to get the id of the underlying function bound to an object by a method-wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following case:

```
>>> "a".capitalize.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x1022e70d8>
>>> "a".capitalize.__call__.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of method-wrapper object at 0x1022e2b70>
>>> id("a".capitalize.__call__)
4331547448
>>> id("a".capitalize.__call__.__call__)
4331547504
>>> id("a".capitalize.__call__) == id("a".capitalize.__call__.__call__)
False
```

How can I establish at runtime that the `__call__` refers to the same base symbol in both cases ?

Edit:
It is possible that expecting something like this to exist for `__call__` in the first place is unreasonable because `__call__` might not have a base symbol that is not bound to any object - in which case what is the best way to detect that other than keeping a list of special names (how can such a list be built authoritatively ?) ?

Comment: They are different objects hence different `id`, whats your eventual goal?

Comment: To be able to decide programmatically that all the .__call__ (just as an example) methods are the same function bound to different objects.

Answer (score 2):

Won't work for `builtin_function_or_method` as they have no `__func__`.

If you're only working with your classes you can compare `__func__`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> b = Foo()
>>> a.bar.__func__
<function Foo.bar at 0x7f6f103e5ae8>
>>> a.bar.__func__ is b.bar.__func__
True
```

But I'd say it's better to do it the other way around: instead of trying to get the function from the instance, get up to the type first:

```
type(a).bar is type(a).bar
```

Which should work even for bltns:

```
>>> type("").capitalize is type("a").capitalize
True
```

And for hierarchies:

```
>>> class A:
...     def foo(self):...
... 
>>> class B(A):...
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> type(a).foo is type(b).foo
True
```

Comment: This also doesn't work in the genral case because different object wrappers have different types:
```type("".capitalize).__call__ is type("a".capitalize.__call__).__call__``` is false

Comment: I mean `type("").capitalize is type("a").capitalize`

Comment: ```id("".capitalize) == id("a".capitalize)``` also works, but I wonder if there is something that works seamlessly for all methods

Comment: Do you mean my `type("").capitalize is type("a").capitalize` does not work seamlessly for all methods?

Comment: I mean type(object).method is type(otherobject).method for all cases of object and otherobject - see edit in my original question.

Comment: well no it doesn't 
```type("".capitalize).__call__ is type("a".capitalize.__call__).__call__```
is still False

Comment: Well, this is not what I've written.